# Are there any advantages to using Windows 7 Ultimate? I can't tell the difference

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I just upgraded my new desktop, which came installed with Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, with a copy of Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit and so far I have not noticed any difference in performance.

Even my Windows Experience Index number is the same 5.5 that it was before the upgrade.

So what's the point, are there any performance advantages that I'm not seeing?

### Additional Info

My system hardware specs:

- AMD quad core 2.6 GHZ
- 1 TB 4200 RPM HDD
- 8 GB DDR2 RAM
- ATI Radeon HD 4650 w/ 1GB dedicated video memory

Comment: You absolutely don't need Windows 7 Ultimate for home unless you want to change the Windows user interface to display menus, dialogs, etc., in a language other than English. If you wanted RDP, EFS, or XP Mode, you could have gone with Windows 7 Professional instead.

Answer (score 13):

There are no performance differences between versions of Windows 7 on the same architecture.

[This](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/compare?T1=tab15) is a list of features right from Microsoft between the most common versions of Win 7.

The big things that you get in Ultimate that you don't get in Home Premium are RDP, Bitlocker, XP Mode, Boot from VHD, and the ability to join domains. Some of these features are available in Professional and all are available in Enterprise edition as well.

Comment: The linked page does not seem to be about Win 7 anymore.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Well, Windows 7 goes End of Extended Support in about a year anyway so the original question itself won't really matter soon.

Comment: Please let me disagree. Even though MS Win 7 Extended Support ended, it doesn't mean this isn't the most popular (and, personal opinion, still the best) Windows version across the world. See. for instance, [this](https://netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx) statistics which shows that Win 7 still the most popular WIn version among the users. Though, the gap between Win 7 and Win 10 is almost non-existent lately, the chart definitely outlines that there is no connection between the MS Support and the real-world popularity.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov - I think we will have to agree to disagree. Anyone who chooses to use an internet-connected device that uses an operating system that does not receive security updates is crazy and shouldn't be placated.

Comment: I believe the issue of choosing Win 10 over Win 7 is completely outside the scope of this question and shouldn't affect answers given here by no means. However, to answer your statement about craziness pf those still on Win 7. Security of Win 7 was developed through all the years it was supported. Also, nobody prevents you from using antivirus\firewall which are still developed with Win 7 security issues in mind (most likely, still all of major ones). From the other side, I'm not sure what makes you think that MS Security patches for Win 10 makes it more secure than Win 7 in its current state.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov I didn't say the answer doesn't matter today. I'm saying that in a year when it's not supported it won't matter. Windows 7 already doesn't support the latest CPUs and hasn't for over a year. And if you think that 3rd party AV and firewalls are a replacement for operating system patches you've got some research to do. But either way, this question was originally answered **EIGHT** years ago. If you care so much about it being updated, find where the official documentation moved and propose an edit.

Comment: If you're not interested in maintaining your answer according to the **current** situation, it's up to you. What would happen in a year is just your speculations. I've never said AV is a magic bullet, just as well as MS Security patches for Win 10 you're advocating. If you've decided to go some route, it's not a reason to name others who don't crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 ultimate is a much bigger OS in terms of size. The only notable differences and language support and bit locker. The bottom line is, unless you really need one of these two features, don't upgrade to ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

there is no definitive difference except n for the bigger taskbar and more compatible programs and recycle bin and faster booting speed and 
little lagging while using browsers there also different backgrounds with more transparency.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question, which asked about performance not features.